# How to display a popup without redirecting to the login page when the Back button is pressed in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

What I want to do is, if I press the back button browser, I have to appear the confirmation popup.

I tried below. but it quickly display the popup then redirect page login. 
can someone help me solve this problem.

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    //  display popup
       }
```

Comment: create a personalized confirmation message if I want to disconnect (back to the login page) or not, when i click on the Back button of the browser.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want. Unfortunately, not all the browsers support a single solution, they all vary depending on the code hence check https://www.irt.org/script/311.htm